# How can I use right double inline view

Tags: mysql, sql, view, inline

In the picture, I want to know the number of states which have coastal = 'Y' and coastal = 'N' separately, and I could get the right result when I used subqueries separately. However, when I put two queries they suddenly multiple 'Y' and 'N'. I have no idea why they gave me strange result.

```
%%sql
Select  count(numcoastal)
From (Select state, count(*) as numcoastal
     From Regions Where coastal ='Y' Group by state)C
    
count(numcoastal)
19

%%sql
Select count(numnot)
From (Select state, count(*) as numnot
     From Regions Where coastal ='N' Group by state)NC

count(numnot)
24

%%sql
Select  count(numcoastal), count(numnot)
From (Select state, count(*) as numcoastal
     From Regions Where coastal ='Y' Group by state)C,
    (Select state, count(*) as numnot
     From Regions Where coastal ='N' Group by state)NC
    
count(numcoastal)   count(numnot)
    456                    456
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (no images), also show us your query attempt. I.e. [mcve].

Comment: Please paste your queries as text into your request, so we can all see them. (Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I added image description, thank you for awareness. If still no images, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query (I've replaced the comma with `CROSS JOIN` as the comma-separated join syntax has been outdated for almost thirty years now):

```
select count(numcoastal), count(numnot)
from 
(
  select state, count(*) as numcoastal 
  from regions 
  where coastal = 'Y' 
  group by state
) c
cross join 
(
  select state, count(*) as numnot 
  from regions 
  where coastal = 'N' 
  group by state
) nc;
```

The cross join gives you all combinations of the sub query results. As the first one gives you 19 rows and the second gives you 24 rows, you'll get 19 x 24 = 456 rows in total. Then you count. As neither `numcoastal` nor `numnot` is null, counting them gives the same as a mere `COUNT(*)` - which is 456.

You would want a full outer join on the state instead. Or even better, use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  state, 
  sum(coastal = 'Y') as numcoastal,
  sum(coastal = 'N') as numnot
from regions 
group by state
order by state;
```

(In MySQL true is 1 and false is 0, so summing up the booelan expression counts the matches.)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know the number of states which have coastal = 'Y' and coastal = 'N' separately

This is conditional aggregation.  Based on your query:

```
select count(distinct case when coastal = 'Y' then state end) as num_coastal,
       count(distinct case when coastal = 'N' then state end) as num_noncoastal
from regions ;
```

If these numbers were the same, it would be because states have multiple rows in `regions`, and all have both flags set.  However, that is not the case in your sample results, so this should do what you want.